# Two Questions on JQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-ui, jquery-effects

So I made a quick signup form here:

http://jsfiddle.net/pBEt2/

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:button').click(function(){
        $('input[type="text"]').each(function(indx){
            var $currentField = $(this);
            if ($currentField.val() === ''){
                $currentField.addClass('empty');
                $('#answer').html("Please fill out all fields");
            } else{
                $currentField.removeClass('empty');
                $('#answer').html("Thank you!");
                $('#answer').effect('blind');
            }
        });
});
});
```

Anyways, once you fill in all fields, it gives you a response that says "Thank you", and I made a Jquery effect (called 'blinds'), that makes the text go up:

1st question:

With the current code, the text "thank you" slides up 4 times because of a total of four inputs. Any reason why? How do I fix this?

2nd question:

How do I make it so the effect doesn't actually go into effect after a few seconds. This way the user can see the text and then allow it to slide up?

Thanks.

Comment: For your second question, use [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/).

Comment: Please post your code here and *do not* subvert the error message by formatting a random bit of your post as code.

Comment: I figured it would be easier to just to read it in fiddle, but that's fine, I'll add it now. Don't want to be breaking rules.

Answer (score 2):

You used `$('input[type="text"]').each(function(indx)...` , and because of this for any `input` that has `type=text` it runs this code:

```
$('#answer').html("Thank you!");
```

I edited your code and your jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('input:button').click(function(){
        var flag = true;
        $('input[type="text"]').each(function(indx){
            var $currentField = $(this);
            if ($currentField.val() === ''){
                $currentField.addClass('empty');
                flag=false;
            } else{
                $currentField.removeClass('empty');
            }
        });
        if(flag){
            $('#answer').css('display','block');
            $('#answer').html("Thank you!");
        }
        else
            $('#answer').html("Please fill out all fields");
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pBEt2/7/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var error = false;
    $('input:button').click(function(){
        $('input[type="text"]').each(function(indx){
            var $currentField = $(this);
            if ($currentField.val() === ''){
                $currentField.addClass('empty');
                $('#answer').html("Please fill out all fields");
                error = true;
            } else{
                $currentField.removeClass('empty');


            }
        });
});

    if(error == true){
          $('#answer').html("Thank you!");
         $('#answer').effect('blind');
    }
});
```

you used each.So it is iterating 4 times.Because we have 4 input fields.BY using this code you can fix the issue.

Comment: That code does not work in JSFiddle. Also, in the if statement at the bottom, it doesn't really make sense to me (I'm a beginner). If error == true, then why do you set error = false?

Comment: otherwise it will remain true if u click second time also

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#answer").slideUp();
    $('input:button').click(function(){
        var correct = true;
        $('input[type="text"]').each(function(indx){
            var $currentField = $(this);
            if ($currentField.val() === ''){
                $currentField.addClass('empty');
                correct=false;
            } else{
                $currentField.removeClass('empty');
            }
        });

        $("#answer").slideDown();
        if(correct){
            $('#answer').html("Thank you!");
            setTimeout(function () {
               $("#answer").slideUp();
            }, 3000);//this is the time you want to wait.
        }
        else{
            $('#answer').html("Please fill out all fields");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I think the "time you want to wait it" is wrong. It doesn't work in jsfiddle (although the rest of the code does). It also just looks wrong since it is outside the function.

Comment: You are right I have change the code that blind it was a problem

Comment: The problem is, I only want it to slide when all the inputs are filled in and it says "Thank you", currently it also slides for "Please fill out all fields".